# How to get a Date object in q when inserting from Java

Tags: java, kdb

According to [QforMortals2](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/atoms#Overview), the equivalent representation of q's `date` is `java.util.Date`.
Likewise, q's `datetime` is equal to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

However, when I push a table from Java to q, q automatically converts the `java.util.Date` object to a `datetime` object, which also has the time included. I then tried to push the object as being `java.sql.Date` and the same thing happened: again q recognised it as a `datetime` atom.

How can I pass Java's `Date` object to q such that q recognised it correctly (without the time)?

Note: I'd rather not specify the table's format beforehand [`"d"$()`], but would rather have that q automatically recognizes the object correctly.

### Update [solved]

Thanks to [user2393012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393012/user2393012) I found my error.

First of all, q does not accept inserts into an undefined table directly. However, when you call upon a process `a` which in turn performs an insert into a process `b`, it **does** allow inserts into undefined tables.

E.g. define a process `b` with `\p 5002`, and define a process `a` with:

```
\p 5001
h:hopen `::5002;
.u.upd:{[x;y] h (insert; x; y)};
```

Now when calling `.u.upd`, it is actually possible to insert into an undefined table in process `b`.

Now when using `c.ks(Object)`, the object should consist of **arrays** which hold the data.

My error was that I defined the data array as

```
new Date[] {new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())}
```

opposed to:

```
new java.sql.Date[] {new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())}
```

Therefore, the `java.sql.Date` got parsed back into a `java.util.Date` when putting it in the array.

The following Java code therefore works as expected:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import kx.c;
import kx.c.*;

public class testingDate {

    public static c conn;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KException, IOException {

        Object[] data     = new Object[] {new java.sql.Date[] {new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())}};
        c.Flip tab        = new c.Flip(new c.Dict(new String[] {"date"}, data));
        Object[] updquery = new Object[] { ".u.upd", "test", tab };

        conn = new c("localhost", 5001);

        try {
            conn.k(updquery);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("error sending data to server.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Which saves the table `test` in process `b` with content:

```
date      
----------
2015.03.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the equivalent representation of q's date is java.util.Date. Likewise, q's datetime is equal to java.sql.Timestamp.

If you are using `c.java` from https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/kx/c.java:

```
Object r() {
     // read from stream
     ....
     case-14:return rd()
     ....
}
Date rd(){int i=ri();return new Date(i==ni?nj:gl(k+86400000L*i));}
```

(`Date` there refers to `java.sql.Date`)

Similarly for what you're doing, i.e. writing a Date to stream (calculating offset for 2000.01.01):

```
void w(Date d){long j=d.getTime();w(j==nj?ni:(int)(lg(j)/86400000-10957));}
```

Looking at the reference page for Java/Kx, http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/:

```
java.util.Date  -15 (=== q datetime)
Date    -14         (=== q date)
```

(latter is java.sql.Date)

If you are using a third party API, it might be different of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as you can see from my initial question, I tried `java.sql.Date` too. Both ended up being converted to `datetime`

Comment: I wonder if you're using a mismatching version of `c.java` with Kdb+? Looking at the latest `c.java` API code it's definately `java.sql.Date` that gets translated as Date. Or are you using a third party API?

Comment: I'm using `c.java` and use it to stream data from Java to Q. However, I'm not using any of the Java functions you mention. I simply create the equivalent Java objects and send them to q in an Object array with `c.ks`. Are there specific functions in `c.java` which should be used to create the objects?

Comment: No, those methods in `c.java` that I mention was just to show it was sql Date that should convert to and from a date type. All you have to do is use the `k` or `ks` method on the API to make a call to KDB. Can you post some code to replicate?

Comment: I found my mistake! Thanks a lot. I've still added the replicating code to show my error.

Comment: Looking backwards it's a rather trivial error, but because my Java code was distributed over multiple classes it was difficult to find it. By trying to replicating the error from scratch, I eventually found it. It's always the most trivial bugs that get you... Thanks again for stressing that the problem was in my Java code.